# RtlValidateHeap error: new [] needs delete [], but DEBUG_NEW needs delete in VC++ 2013 express

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to get old code from VC++ 6 working in VC++ 2013 express.  After jumping through many hoops to use MFC with Visual Studio 2013 Express (download old version of WDK/DDK to get MFC, fix bugs in header files etc) I have it compiling, but I get an "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" error when running.

Turns out this is due to confusion between "delete" and "delete []".  Older versions of VC++ didn't seem to mind which way to deleted arrays, but VS2013 does.  But worse than that, if you use DEBUG_NEW, ie "#define new DEBUG_NEW" is near the start of your C++ files, then it switches which delete you need to use!

For me, new [] must be matched with delete [] when not using DEBUG_NEW, but delete (without []) must be used when using DEBUG_NEW!  If not, I get that runtime error again.

Is this due to using an old version of DEBUG_NEW, from an old version of MFC?  The Express version doesn't provide MFC, so I can't simply use the new version.

How can I use DEBUG_NEW and still match new [] with delete [] (as required when DEBUG_NEW is not active)?

Thanks,
Rob.

Comment: To make matters worse, some MFC headers make use of DEBUG_NEW, and hence crash when they make correct use of delete[].  So I can't even avoid the problem by not using DEBUG_NEW in my own code.

Comment: For example, CArray uses DEBUG_NEW and thus crashes.

Comment: I tried commenting out places where new was #defined as DEBUG_NEW in the MFC header files, which gets me past the CArray crash, but then it just crashes in a call to CWnd::DestroyWindow().  No doubt use of DEBUG_NEW is compiled into the library which I can't do anything about.

Is this futile?